# Why does namespace after method call changes?

Tags: python, namespaces

I'm creating a class, but having some trouble with the namespacing in python.

You can see the code below, and it mostly works ok, but after the call to `guiFrame._stateMachine()` the time module is somehow not defined anymore.

If I re-import the time module in `_stateMachine()` it works. But why is the time module not in the namespace when I import it in the head?

Am I missing something?

The error message:

```
  File "C:\Scripts\Python\GUI.py", line 106, in <module>
    guiFrame._stateMachine()
  File "C:\Scripts\Python\GUI.py", line 74, in _stateMachine
    self.tempfile.write('%s cpuUMTS %s\n' % (time.asctime(time.localt
f.load.cpuThreadsValue['10094']))
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'time' referenced before assignment
```

The code:

```
import os
import cpu_load_internal
import throughput_internal
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
import time
class GUIFramework(Frame):
    """This is the GUI"""

    def __init__(self,master=None):
        """Initialize yourself"""

        """Initialise the base class"""
        Frame.__init__(self,master)

        """Set the Window Title"""
        self.master.title("Type Some Text")

        """Display the main window
        with a little bit of padding"""
        self.grid(padx=10,pady=10)
        self.CreateWidgets()
        plt.figure(1)

    def _setup_parsing(self):
        self.load = cpu_load_internal.CPULoad('C:\Templogs')
        self.throughput = throughput_internal.MACThroughput('C:\Templogs')
        self.tempfile = open('output.txt','w')
        self.state = 0        

    def _parsing(self):
        self.load.read_lines()
        self.throughput.read_lines()
        self.cpuLoad.set(self.load.cpuThreadsValue['10094'])
        self.macThroughput.set(self.throughput.macULThroughput)         

    def __change_state1(self):
        self.state = 2

    def __change_state3(self):
        self.state = 3     

    def CreateWidgets(self):
        """Create all the widgets that we need"""

        """Create the Text"""
        self.cpuLoad = StringVar()
        self.lbText1 = Label(self, textvariable=self.cpuLoad)
        self.lbText1.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.macThroughput = StringVar()
        self.lbText2 = Label(self, textvariable=self.macThroughput)
        self.lbText2.grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.butStart = Button(self, text = 'Start', command = self.__change_state1)
        self.butStart.grid(row=1, column=0)

        self.butStop = Button(self, text = 'Stop', command = self.__change_state3)
        self.butStop.grid(row=1, column=1)

    def _stateMachine(self):
        if (self.state == 2):
            print self.throughput.macULUpdate
            print self.load.cpuUpdate

            if self.load.cpuUpdate:
                self.load.cpuUpdate = 0
                print 'cpuUMTS %s\n' % (self.load.cpuThreadsValue['10094'])
                self.tempfile.write('%s cpuUMTS %s\n' % (time.asctime(time.localtime()), self.load.cpuThreadsValue['10094']))            

            if self.throughput.macULUpdate:
                self.throughput.macULUpdate = 0
                print 'macUL %s %s\n' % (self.throughput.macULThroughput, self.throughput.macULThroughputUnit)
                self.tempfile.write('%s macUL %s %s\n' % (time.asctime(time.localtime()), self.throughput.macULThroughput, self.throughput.macULThroughputUnit))

        if (self.state == 3):
            self.tempfile.seek(0)
            plt.plot([1,2,3],[1,4,6])
            plt.savefig('test.png')
            self.state == 0
            while 1:
                try:
                    line = (self.tempfile.next())
                except:
                    break

                if 'cpuUMTS' in line:
                    line.split
                    time = 4


if __name__ == "__main__":
    guiFrame = GUIFramework()
    print dir(guiFrame)
    guiFrame._setup_parsing()
    guiFrame.state = 2
    while(1):
        guiFrame._parsing()
        guiFrame._stateMachine()
        guiFrame.update()
        time.sleep(0.1)
```

Answer (score 7):

Why do you assign to `time`? You can't use it as local variable, it will overshadow the module! If you look closely it complains that you use `time` before you assign to it -- since to use it as a local variable in `_stateMachine`.

```
time = 4
```

Comment: Oops.. (:

I got a little carried away and somehow confused with the error. Of course that is the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You seem to use time as a variable. What happens here:

> "C:\Scripts\Python\GUI.py", line 74

Answer (score 2):

You try to assing to the variable `time` in this method:

```
time = 4
```

Therefore the compiler assumes that time must be a local variable, which isn't true. And that is the reason why you get this error when you want to use the module `time`, even if you try to use the module before you assign to `time`.